# How to make files available as a download link in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

In my asp.net website, users can upload multiple files, which reside in 'upload' folder on server's hard drive. I am saving the files by renaming them with username + original file name
Example : if I upload file 'user.text' and my code is 1000, then the file will be saved in upload folder with name '1000_user.Text'. This is for identification of file against a particular user.
Now, when admin logs in application and selects a user, he should be able to see all files uploaded by him/her. Files should be in downloadable format to him.

How can I achieve the same? I have totally no idea, how to go for it ?

Comment: Check this http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/185886/File-Upload-and-Download-in-ASP-NET

Comment: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/02/saveupload-files-in-folder-and-download.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you ask a question on SO. Anyway already a piece of advice :

1. Store your files OUTSIDE of the webroot, and use a script in your website to get the files and render it to the user. This is for security reason : if someone manages to upload a malicious file, you don't want him to be able to execute it from the web.
2. Store file info and upload info in a database : who uploaded what and when ? Relying on file name isn't a good idea. You could also store the file in the database eventually (as a BLOB), but I prefer the good old filesystem

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you couple of ways based on feasibility. Approach 1 - If you can make database changes, when user is uploading a file you should save dynamically generated filename against the user in database. This way when admin logs in and wants to see all the files uploaded by user, you just need to make a database query and show them in a grid. When user clicks on the file name, you can fetch the file from harddisk and allow it to download to admin.

If database change is not feasible, your task will be more difficult. You will have to query in your directory with username in all the files. You can make use of LINQ to make this task little easier to you. Once you have got all the list, show it to admin.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to save metadata about the file on the database (like original file name and username). Then you could use this metadata to find the files that the user have uploaded. Give the files a file name on disk that is based on a unique ID in the database table. That way a user can upload several files with the same name. Make sure that this folder is not located within you application so that they are accessible with a url for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The most recommended way to achieve this is to use a database, it is same as a module of Gallery where a user has albums and some pictures in albums. Admin can view each user's album and pictures in the album. you have to introduce two tables in your database. I having the category information of files being uploaded (master table) and other table having the info about the files itself (details table).

The other way is to create a hierarchal folder directory for each user for file categories in your application and then recursively read the directories and fields and then list them up to show them to application users. this would be costly i guess when number of files will increase.